# VS2013 build not including binaries for Nuget dependencies of project dependency

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I have a console app project (call it App) in a large solution that includes a library project (call it Lib) that my app needs to use.

App has a project reference to Lib and Lib has references to a number of Nuget packages. When the solution is built the binaries from the Nuget packages are included in the bin folder for Lib, but while the binary for Lib itself is included in the bin folder for App, the binaries from the Nuget packages it depends on are not.

This causes runtime errors in App when code in Lib attempts to reflect its dependencies.

Is there something I should be setting to ensure that Nuget dependencies of project dependencies are included? I can reference the Nuget packages directly in App but there are many of them and I would rather work out the correct way of ensuring that the dependencies are resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three options:

1. Create a post-build event that copies all the binaries from `Lib` to `App`
2. Include references to all of the binaries that are required for `App` to run in the project.
3. Make `Lib` into a NuGet package and then use NuGet to manage the `Lib` dependency. All the binaries would be included.

Option 2 is my general approach, although a case could be made for any of these.

Comment: Thanks. The first option sounds like it might be more resistant to future changes to Lib's dependencies.

Comment: It is, but it's also more opaque as to what the application's actual dependencies are. I just added a third option: NuGet.

Comment: True, I'll probably just add each one that fails, then test for the next failure, until I get them all. It is reflecting them all so I'm not likely to miss any.